# Leave specific routes without effect in ruby on rails and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rubygems

Good evening how could I cancel or delete these 2 routes, I also want to know how I can redirect to another site if I am not logged in
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhea1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the routes by using skip, then specify the routes you still use. something like this:

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions] do
    delete "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_user_session
    post "/admin" => "devise/sessions#create", :as => :user_session
end
```

Devise already have a feature for auto redirect. Go to `application_controller.rb` and add this `before_action :authenticate_user!`

I'm not 100% sure this works now that we've disabled the default session paths. The alternative is to create our own method to override it in `application_controller.rb`

Something like this:

```
protected
  def authenticate_user!
    if user_signed_in?
      super
    else
      redirect_to login_path
    end
  end
```